# followed urllib.request.urlopen documentation but still not working

Tags: python, urllib

I followed the documentation but still getting errors which I can't figure out. I am using Python 3.

Here is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen('http://pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html')

bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")
print(bs.h1)
```

[Code Editor with code and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vl5Gg.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Instead of linking to an image, would you mind editing your post and typing out the error?

Comment: It's not a problem with your code. The error message says there's a problem with the server's SSL certificate.

Comment: Which is strange because I went to that page and the certificate expires in March of this year.  Perhaps the date on @William's box is off.

Comment: @William, can you run `import time; print(time.asctime())`?

Comment: @DanielWalker The domain certificate itself and the two intermediate certificates are valid, but it seems like the root certificate has problems. It is a common problem when the root or intermediate certificate expires but some domain certificates based on it are still valid.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  TIL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did everything right.

The URL you supplied uses `HTTPS` and the error you get is related to the certificate problems on the website.

If you are trying to learn new things, just change the URL to some other example website.

If you want to get the result from a specific URL no matter the cost, add keyword argument `context` to your `urlopen` call and provide a correct SSL context for it to work:

```
from ssl import create_default_context, CERT_NONE
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
context = create_default_context()
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
html = urlopen('http://pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html', context=context)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")
print(bs.h1)
```